# Creating Multiple Line Listview in Android-Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, listview, mono, xamarin

I want the listview to display multiple lines of text.2 lines of text in addition to the one displayed.
What is the best approach to do this?

For now i have created a simple listview,added a row xml file,and populated the listview in code

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace uitest
{
    [Activity (Label = "uitest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity :ListActivity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            var kittens = new [] { "Fluffy", "Muffy", "Tuffy" };

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter (
                this, //Context, typically the Activity
                Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, //The layout. How the data will be presented 
                kittens //The enumerable data
            );

            this.ListAdapter = adapter; 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display more dynamic data in it.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add or remove the list items dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You would subclass BaseAdapter or BaseAdapter< T > and handle item view creation. Read [this document](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance/).